# Interpretar y mostrar datos en tabla con JQuery desde una matriz en JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo la siguiente duda, soy nuevo en programación y Javascript. Tengo el siguiente esquema que no me dibuja los datos de la siguiente matriz en una tabla;

```
{
  "drivers": [
    {
      "status": false,
      "_id": "5d9ae12982c02e0017fdbda4",
      "name": "Marcos",
      "lastName": "self",
      "__v": 0
    }
    {
      "status": false,
      "_id": "5d9ae12982c02e0017fdbda4",
      "name": "will",
      "lastName": "Mendoza",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Quiero mostrar en una tabla esos datos, pero ya me perdí en esa parte con each, o quiza este por el camino equivocado:

```
Object.keys(drivers).forEach( drivers => {

    tbody.append(`
    <tr>
    <td class="_id">${drivers._id}</td>
    <td class="name">${drivers.name}</td>
    <td class="lastName">${drivers.lastName}</td>
    </tr>
    `)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

El valor de la propiedad `drivers` es un array, entonces lo puedes recorrer directamente y cada iteración será una fila.

```js
const obj = {
  "drivers": [{
      "status": false,
      "_id": "5d9ae12982c02e0017fdbda4",
      "name": "Marcos",
      "lastName": "self",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "status": false,
      "_id": "5d9ae12982c02e0017fdbda4",
      "name": "will",
      "lastName": "Mendoza",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}

obj.drivers.forEach(driver => {
  console.log(driver._id);
  console.log(driver.name);
  console.log(driver.lastName);
});
```

`Object.keys` serviría para tener un array de los keys de un objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas:

- Iterar sobre los elementos, accediendo primero al nombre de la variable que los contiene, a la cual le llamé `informacion`
- Una vez hecho accedes a la clave principal que los contiene a los demás: `drivers`
- Usamos `tbody` para englobar a las filas que se llenarán automáticamente con el uso del `forEach`
- Con el uso del `forEach` recorremos los valores obtenidos y los asignamos a la fila obtenida en la constante `fila`, *debemos hacer uso de `+=`* para que tome todos los valores y dibuje las filas, en caso contrario si solo haces `=` solo tomará el último valor de la iteración y será el que muestre en la tabla
- La estructura generada la asignamos con `innerHTML` empezando con `<tr></tr>`
- La impresión la realizamos a través de *template strings* indicando que acceda a la variable `elemento` y a cada una de las `claves` de la data recorrida

Código

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Ejemplo</title>
      <style>
        tr, td, th{
          border: 1px solid red;
        }
      </style>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>_id</th>
          <th>name</th>
          <th>lastName</th>
          <th>__v</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="datos">
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    let informacion = {
      "drivers": [
        {
          "status": false,
          "_id": "5d9ae12982c02e0017fdbda4",
          "name": "Marcos",
          "lastName": "self",
          "__v": 0
        },
        {
          "status": false,
          "_id": "5d9ae12982c02e0017fdbda4",
          "name": "will",
          "lastName": "Mendoza",
          "__v": 0
        }
      ]
    }
    
    const fila = document.querySelector(".datos")
    informacion.drivers.forEach((elemento) => {
      fila.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${elemento.status}</td><td>${elemento._id}</td><td>${elemento.name}</td><td>${elemento.lastName}</td><td>${elemento.__v}</td></tr>`
    })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```